# unable to mount a damaged micro sd card

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, hard-drive, micro-sd

Hi all and thanks in advance for your help.

I am running ubuntu on a virtual box trying to recover a damaged micro sd card. i have tried using photorec however it does not see the drive. I have the following log from dmesg if this helps. Many thanks

```
[  946.123397] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05dc, idProduct=b051
[  946.123399] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[  946.123400] usb 1-2: Product: microSD RDR 
[  946.123402] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Lexar
[  946.123403] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 000000000001
[  946.126923] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  946.126972] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[  947.177453] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Lexar    microSD RDR      0815 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  947.178795] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  967.121400] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  968.160450] .
[  974.851898] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1169.941704] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 1275.788224] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ohci-pci
[ 1276.268472] usb 1-2: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x81 has invalid maxpacket 512, setting to 64
[ 1276.268475] usb 1-2: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x2 has invalid maxpacket 512, setting to 64
[ 1276.298352] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=b7b2
[ 1276.298354] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[ 1276.298355] usb 1-2: Product: MobileMate Micro
[ 1276.298357] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 1276.298358] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 000000026855
[ 1276.302569] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1276.302618] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[ 1277.336988] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   9412 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 1277.338343] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 1277.611724] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 124735488 512-byte logical blocks: (63.9 GB/59.5 GiB)
[ 1277.636273] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 1277.636275] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 1277.660897] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 1277.660901] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1282.561039] scsi_io_completion: 2 callbacks suppressed
[ 1282.561043] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1282.561045] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1282.561047] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1282.561049] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1282.561050] print_req_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[ 1282.561051] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1282.561054] buffer_io_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[ 1282.561054] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1282.594099] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1282.594102] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1282.594104] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1282.594105] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1282.594107] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1282.594110] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1282.628745] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1282.628747] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1282.628748] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1282.628750] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1282.628751] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1282.628754] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1282.628761] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 1282.666993] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1282.666995] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1282.666996] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1282.666998] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1282.666999] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1282.667001] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1282.697735] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1282.697737] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1282.697738] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1282.697740] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1282.697741] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1282.697743] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1282.735851] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1282.735853] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1282.735855] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1282.735857] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1282.735858] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1282.735860] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1282.774111] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1282.774114] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1282.774115] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1282.774131] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1282.774133] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1282.774135] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1282.774142] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 1282.800415] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1282.800417] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1282.800418] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1282.800420] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1282.800421] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1282.800424] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1282.839662] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1282.839664] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1282.839666] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1282.839668] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1282.839669] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1282.839671] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1282.877090] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1282.877092] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1282.877094] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1282.877096] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 08 00
[ 1282.877097] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 24
[ 1282.877099] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3, async page read
[ 1282.943976]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[ 1282.972647] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1395.644556] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 1817.180305] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ohci-pci
[ 1817.656569] usb 1-2: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x81 has invalid maxpacket 512, setting to 64
[ 1817.656572] usb 1-2: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x2 has invalid maxpacket 512, setting to 64
[ 1817.682718] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=b7b2
[ 1817.682720] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
[ 1817.682722] usb 1-2: Product: MobileMate Micro
[ 1817.682723] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 1817.682724] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 000000026855
[ 1817.686898] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1817.686944] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[ 1818.718746] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   9412 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 1818.719976] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 1818.990256] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 124735488 512-byte logical blocks: (63.9 GB/59.5 GiB)
[ 1819.014731] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 1819.014733] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[ 1819.042261] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 1819.042265] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1823.933202] scsi_io_completion: 2 callbacks suppressed
[ 1823.933206] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1823.933209] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1823.933210] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1823.933212] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1823.933213] print_req_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[ 1823.933214] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1823.933217] buffer_io_error: 2 callbacks suppressed
[ 1823.933218] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1823.970146] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1823.970148] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1823.970150] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1823.970152] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1823.970153] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1823.970156] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1824.001014] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1824.001016] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1824.001017] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1824.001019] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1824.001020] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1824.001023] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1824.001031] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 1824.038301] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1824.038303] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1824.038305] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1824.038307] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1824.038308] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1824.038311] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1824.072840] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1824.072842] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1824.072844] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1824.072846] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1824.072847] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1824.072849] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1824.104211] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1824.104214] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1824.104216] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1824.104219] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1824.104220] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1824.104224] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1824.143389] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1824.143392] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1824.143394] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1824.143396] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1824.143397] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1824.143400] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1824.143409] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 1824.174994] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1824.174997] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1824.174998] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1824.175001] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1824.175002] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1824.175005] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1824.209046] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1824.209048] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1824.209050] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1824.209052] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 1824.209053] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[ 1824.209056] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 1824.245456] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1824.245459] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[ 1824.245460] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Medium not present
[ 1824.245462] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 08 00
[ 1824.245464] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 24
[ 1824.245467] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3, async page read
[ 1824.311208]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[ 1824.340658] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1824.385747] sdb: detected capacity change from 63864569856 to 0
[ 1895.436074] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6
[ 1895.436078] ata1.00: failed command: IDENTIFY DEVICE
[ 1895.436083] ata1.00: cmd ec/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 0 pio 512 in
                        res 01/04:01:01:14:eb/00:00:00:00:00/a0 Emask 0x3 (HSM violation)
[ 1895.436085] ata1.00: status: { ERR }
[ 1895.436087] ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
[ 1895.436198] ata1: soft resetting link
[ 1895.596642] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/33
[ 1895.596937] ata1: EH complete
```

Comment: You may want to try other cardreader. But it is very likely that microsd is dead.

Comment: Hi, I have tried a couple different card readers and also different usb ports.

Comment: I feared the card may be dead however i was hopeful when i seen that it read the correct 64gb size of the drive.

Comment: Symptoms are not good. Last chance is to insert into full SD adaptor and enable write protect on it. Then try to take full backup.

Comment: cool, have you got a guide for that anywhere?

Comment: I mean [mechanical switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#/media/File:SD_card_unlocked_and_locked.svg) on [full SD adaptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#/media/File:Sdadaptersandcards.jpg).

Comment: It doesn't show up at all when I use a full sd adapter. Only when I use usb adaptor. Not sure I'm trying to mount the SD reader correctly

Comment: The tools that are available for regular users (like you and me) require that the SD card can be seen as a mass storage device (that command line  tools like `lsblk` can see it). Otherwise it is probably damaged beyond repair or recovery of the files. There is a list of things to try before giving up on the drive at the following link, [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)